SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727) or _ssl.c:1000
The problem
When I run pip install certifi (or python -m pip install certifi) (pip2), I get the error
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727)

or if I run pip3 install certifi, I get the error
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:1000)

.
As a result I can't pip install anything, not even the certifi package which some people have said can resolve this very type of error.
Information about my setup

I am running MacOS Ventura 13.4.
It has both a Python 2.7 and a Python 3.12 installation on it, as well as a brew install and a conda install, as I'm a Python developer and experiment with many things.
There are various paths for ssl certs on my machine. I am aware of:

/usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/2024-07-02/share/ca-certificates/cacert.pem
~/ca_certs -- symbolic link to --> /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates --> symbolic link to --> ../Cellar/ca-certificates/2024-07-02/share/ca-certificates
/etc/ssl/cert.pem
/private/etc/ssl/cert.pem


I believe my Python installation looks for certs here:

$ python -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)'
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/etc/openssl/cert.pem

(which I've symlinked to my cert file also) and similar for Python 3.
What I've tried
I've tried setting up symlinks so that all of these locations are pointing to the same cert file in the end.
I've tried following the solution detailed here which seemed very promising.  I downloaded the latest Firefox certs and discovered they were the same as the ones I already had.  Then I created the self-signed certificate as instructed, and added its contents to my cert.pem file.
I've tried running the Install Certificates.command file to install the certificates, but it fails with the same error because the script that it runs uses pip.
All to no avail.  I just keep getting the same errors.  And I really want to know why.
Thank you in advance for your help.  In the meantime I'll be trying to read more about the specific numbers 727 and 1000 to see if there is a more specific error message.
Updates
UPDATE 1: I tried using the pip --cert option as described here with each of the cert files I've described above.  None of them work.
UPDATE 2: I tried installing certifi from a wheel.  With pip3 I hit the same error.  With pip2 I found an older version of certifi (2020.12.5) and it installed successfully.  Subsequent pip installs using pip2 still failed with the same error.
UPDATE 3: I tried using the --trusted-host option with the three URLs suggested here.  This seems to be working, and I can install anything with pip2 or pip3.  I have not tried the permanent solution yet.  Is this safe and should I continue with this solution?

I recall that there is some sort of ssl command you can run to test our ssl directly and maybe get more specific error messages

If you read the Read me when installing 2.7 it says: The bundled pip has its own default certificate store for verifying download connections. So the things you've tried won't affect pip. I don't have a solution but I'll think about it some more.

Sorry, I actually installed 2.7.18. Which subminor version of python 2 are you running? Same question for the pip module? My install of python 2.7.18 has version pip version 19.2.3 and it is able to install without those certificate errors.

note to self: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi/26062583#26062583

Did --cert work for you?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk --cert didn't work (see update at bottom).  I have pip 19.2.3 and python 2.7.18.  Thank you kindly for your comments and ideas.  And also I've been trying with pip3 version 24.0 and python3 version 3.12.4.

If you actually visit https://pypi.org in a web browser does it work? Are there any certificate warnings or errors? What certificate does the browser report?

@nneonneo Yes I can visit that website just fine and I can also download the .tar.gz and .whl files just fine.  Do you suggest I download the wheel and then install that so that pip won't have to download anything?  I don't know how to look up the certificate that the browser reports.  I found an error message in the console that says "None of the “sha512” hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the subresource. The computed hash is “z4PhNX7vuL3xVChQ1m2AB9Yg5AULVxXcg/SpIdNs6c5H0NE8XYXysP+DGNKHfuwvY7kxvUdBeoGlODJ6+SfaPg==”.", but I have no idea if that's relevant or not.

I think it might be easiest to download the certifi package wheel from the PyPI website directly, install that with pip, and then see if the problem persists.

Please see the two most recent updates.  Should I trust this trusted-host solution?
